# Weird \U0000202a and \U0000202c characters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

I bumped into an interesting situation while I am writing an application about contact list.

The weird situation is that after I successfully managed to retrieve contacts from the iPhone's list, some phone numbers listed as;

@"\U0000202a xxx xxx xxxx\U0000202c".

When I try to use;

```
modifiedPN = [modifiedPN stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

and

```
modifiedPN = [modifiedPN stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\U0000202" withString:@""];
```

**nothing changes.**

I also tried

```
[mPN containsString:@" "]
```

and

```
[mPN containsString:@"\\U0000202"]
```

**but they both returns "NO"**

I think this problem occurs when user was saved from Whatsapp.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

I only want the phone number without spaces or weird \U0000202 charachter.

Comment: `U0000202` != `U0000202a`

Comment: FYI - U+202A is the "Left-to-right embedding" character and U+202C is the "Pop directional formatting" character.

Comment: @vadian I know that U0000202 != U0000202a. How about U0000202a contains U0000202. I check whether the string **contains** U0000202 or not.

Comment: @rmaddy how can I check these characters?

Comment: @OnurŞahindur No, you don't, because an Unicode token is not the same as a literal string.

Comment: The \Uetc should count as ONE character, not a string with various characters, that's why you have "issue" with the `containsString:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go the other way and extract the number:

```
NSString *numString = @"\U0000202a 123 456 7890\U0000202c";

NSString *extractedString = [[numString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                        [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                       componentsJoinedByString:@""];

// extractedString = 1234567890
```

This also works with (123) 456 7890

Comment: This will fail in many ways. What if `numString` is something like `(123) 456-6789`?

Comment: Updated, revised one handles everything & is much more concise

Comment: @CodeBender you saved my day! Thanks a lot. That is the right answer.

Comment: Cool & @rmaddy Thanks for the catch

Comment: Instead you could create a character set with just the two Unicodes and strip just that from your `numString`.